# MDX Error: referring the calculated measure (using with member) within a subcube return an error

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm pretty new to MDX. Can you please help me out in clearing this concept. Your help is appreciated.

I've the below MDX query which executes perfectly fine.

```
with member [measures].[perc] as
([Dim Customer].[Customer ID].currentmember,[Measures].[Amount])

select
[measures].[perc] on 0,
[Dim Customer].[Customer ID].children on 1
from [Analysis DW]
```

But, when I try to refer [measure].[perc], I get an error saying **"The '[perc]' member was not found in the cube when the string, [measures].[perc], was parsed.**"

Please find below the error mdx script for reference-

```
with 
 member [measures].[perc] as
([Dim Customer].[Customer ID].currentmember,[Measures].[Amount])

select [measures].[perc]  on 0
from
    (
       select
       [measures].[perc] on 0,
       [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].children on 1
        from [Analysis DW]
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

***Coming a lot late, but thought this could benefit someone with a similar problem.***

Your MDX query fails because the calculated measure is out of context for the subcube. You are declaring **[Measures].[perc]** above the MDX select snippet. So, by design, it is *visible* to the select following it. ***But*** it is not visible to the subcube inside the **Select**. Thus the following piece of code makes no sense at all to the SSAS engine.

```
   select
   [measures].[perc] on 0, //Compiler is like .... WHAT THE %@#^ ??
   [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].children on 1
   from [Analysis DW]
```

It is as good as writing

```
   select
   [measures].[RandomGarbageName] on 0, 
   [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].children on 1
   from [Analysis DW]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just try

```
     with 
     member [measures].[perc] as
     ([Dim Customer].[Customer ID].currentmember,[Measures].[Amount])

     select
     [measures].[perc] on 0,
     [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].children on 1
     from [Analysis DW]
```

Comment: Thanks Bhupesh for your answer. I know that I can get result for the above example provided without a subselect. Here I'm curious to know the reason which is not enabling us to select the calculated member within a subselect. If I'm able to reference the calculated with member in the subselect I will be able to solve some of the complex scenarios with ease.